# Changing CSS class of ASP.NET items on button click in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am having trouble changing the css of ASP.NET items on click of buttons.

I know I am able to do this;

```
ASPxButton2.Attributes("class") = "Block-Button Button-Blue"
```

However you can't send objects through CommandArguments (as far as I know).

And you don't have an Attributes method on FindControl.

My question is, how can I send/get 3 separate lists of object on a OnClick event in codebehind to change their css class? Alternatively is there a way to get the item by it's ID as a string like GetElementById("ElementID")

Comment: `c#` and `vb.net`?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty If someone helped me in c# i could convert to vb.net quite easliy just wanted to broaden the help search

Answer (score 0):

You can assign commandargument for the button, or assign string or serialised json in hidden field on client side.

In both cases you will be able to access values on server side.